# String tokenizing

Tags: java, string

I want to tokenize a string `private String requestDate="12/12/2012 02:02:23 AM";` to

> 12122012_020223am_

how to achieve this using stringTokenizer ?

Regards,

Comment: Did you maybe mean: `String requestDate="12/12/2012 02:02:23 AM"` to `12122012_020223_am`?

Comment: Do it using `SimpleDateFormat` not `StringTokenizer`.

Answer (score 2):

```
requestDate = requestDate.replaceAll("/", "");
requestDate = requestDate.replaceAll(" ", "_");
requestDate = requestDate.replaceAll(":", "");
```

will give you 12122012_020223_AM

then requestDate = requestDate.toLowerCase()

will give 12122012_020223_am

Comment: You can chain all these together too: `requestDate = requestDate.replaceAll("/", "").replaceAll(" ", "_").toLowerCase()`

Comment: Nice am simple solution, but you forgot the `:`s. And you could replace `_AM` with `am_` to move that last underscore to the end.

Comment: Thanks I added that, the am_ doesn't really make sense I think it is a type error, but we could use replace all again for that part

Answer (score 1):

Using [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a").parse(requestDate);
String output = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyy_hhmmssa_").format(date);
output = output.toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want StringTokenise something like this should do it

```
@Test
public void test() {
    StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer("ab/c/d EF", "/");
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        StringTokenizer stringTokenizer2 = new StringTokenizer(stringTokenizer.nextToken(), " ");
        while (stringTokenizer2.hasMoreTokens()) {
            b.append(stringTokenizer2.nextToken().toLowerCase());
            b.append("_");
        }
    }
    assertEquals("ab_c_d_ef_", b.toString());
}
```

One of the StringTokenizer [constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) takes a string and a delimeter